# Target specific arrow to change sorting in table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table

I am creating a table that is using arrows to display if the sort is ascending or descending. The problem is that when I click a an arrow on one column all of the arrows move. I want to where the specific arrow clicked on only changes the direction of the column that I clicked on. I am trying to match the arrow clicked with the name of the key value of the th I have been working on this logic for some time and can't seem to get it down. can someone point me in the right direction

Code

```
const sortTable = (key) => {
        setSortDirection(!sortDirection);
        const clonedOptions = [...listOfOptions];
        clonedOptions.sort((a, b) => {
            return sortDirection ? a[key] - b[key] : b[key] - a[key];
        })
        console.log(key)
        setListOfOptions(clonedOptions);

        const arrows = document.querySelectorAll('.fas')
        arrows.forEach(arrow => {
            if (sortDirection === true) {
                arrow.classList.add('arrowup')
            } else if (sortDirection === false) {
                arrow.classList.remove('arrowup')
            }
        })
    }

 <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th onClick={() => sortTable('clock')}>Date </th>
                            <th onClick={() => sortTable('name')}>Stock Name <span><i onClick={() => sortTable('name')} className="fas fa-sort-up"></i></span></th>
                            <th onClick={() => sortTable('price')}>Price Of Option <span><i onClick={() => sortTable('price')} className="fas fa-sort-up"></i></span></th>
                            <th onClick={() => sortTable('amountOfOptions')}>Number Of Options <span><i onClick={() => sortTable('amountOfOptions')} className="fas fa-sort-up"></i></span></th>
                            <th onClick={() => sortTable('totalAmountSpent')}>Total Amount Spent <span><i onClick={() => sortTable('totalAmountSpent')} className="fas fa-sort-up"></i></span></th>
                            <th onClick={() => sortTable('optionPriceSoldAt')}>Option Sold At <span><i onClick={() => sortTable('optionPriceSoldAt')} className="fas fa-sort-up"></i></span></th>
                            <th onClick={() => sortTable('amountOfOptionsSold')}>Options Sold <span><i onClick={() => sortTable('amountOfOptionsSold')} className="fas fa-sort-up"></i></span></th>
                            <th onClick={() => sortTable('totalProfit')}>Proft <span><i onClick={() => sortTable('totalProfit')} className="fas fa-sort-up"></i></span></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    {listOfOptions.map((option) => {
                        return (
                            <tbody key={uuidv1()}>
                                <tr>
                                    <td title="delete" onClick={() => deleteOption(option.id)}><span className="delete">x</span></td>
                                    <td>{option.clock}</td>
                                    <td>{option.name.toUpperCase()}</td>
                                    <td>${option.price}</td>
                                    <td>{option.amountOfOptions}</td>
                                    <td>${option.totalAmountSpent.toFixed(2)}</td>
                                    <td>${option.optionPriceSoldAt}</td>
                                    <td>{option.amountOfOptionsSold}</td>
                                    <td style={{ color: option.totalProfit >= 0 ? 'green' : 'red' }}>${option.totalProfit.toFixed(2)}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        )
                    })}
                </table>
```

Comment: just as a FYI, calling `setSortDirection` at the beginning of your function doesn't mean that `sortDirection` has been updated in the following lines of code. It is asynchronous

Comment: @John Ruddell, Hi, what does that mean?

Comment: I think your specific issue is the logic around what arrow to select. `document.querySelectorAll('.fas')` will give you all of the arrows. When really you just want one. Why don't you just store the active filter in component state and reuse that when determining which row to sort / which arrow to rotate?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would recommend you to create a hardcoded object of the headers of the table like this:

```
const tableHeaders = [{id: "clock", label: "Date"}, {id: "name", label: "Stock Name"}, ...] // and so on
```

Once you got that, you can simplify all the `th` elements with this:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    {tableHeaders.map(({id, label}) => // destructuring value here
      <th key={id} onClick={() => sortTable(id)}>{label} <span><i onClick={() => sortTable(id)} className="fas fa-sort-up"></i></span></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

Ok but now with your problem, you should not in almost every case use vanilla js to target  elements in the DOM to change their classes, etc. So how can you change the className of an element in react dinamically?

Modifying the above code with this:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    {tableHeaders.map(({id, label}) => // destructuring value here
      <th key={id} onClick={() => sortTable(id)}>{label} <span><i onClick={() => sortTable(id)} className={`fas fa-sort-up ${sortedColumns.includes(id) ? "arrowup" : ""`}></i></span></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

So you don't have `sortedColumns` defined, so you need a state that's an array with the ids of all sorted headers.

```
const [sortedColumns, setSortedColumns] = useState([]) // no column sorted at first
```

And finally you should modify `sortTable` to add the sorted columns into the array (or remove them, aka. `filter`). Leave that to you :)